# Solving IVP:s with Laplace transformation

Tags: differential-equations

In SymPy 1.7.1, there is no support for solving  Initial Value Problems (IVP) with Laplace Transforms. It is well-known, that Matlab (Symbolic ToolBox) has this possibility. Will there be a future SymPy upgrade which has this support?

Comment: Sympy has a solver for linear DE with constant coefficients. Do you expect the Laplace routine to be able to solve cases with non-constant coefficients? In the constant-coefficients case, how do you suppose to recognize a solution via Laplace from a solution via characteristic polynomial and variation of constants? Or are you asking about the Laplace transform as a tool first and possible applications to linear ODE second?

Comment: I am working with a project to replace Matlab with Python, in a  calculus course.  Explicitly, following problem is solved in Matlab. It is an inhomogenous IVP with constant coefficients. In Matlab Code: Dy=diff(y(t),t);
D2y=diff(Dy,t);
g=8*t*(heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-5))+40*heaviside(t-5);
ode=D2y+4*y-g ==0;  My goal is to Laplace transform the equation, obtain a solution in frequency domain, and finally transform it back to time domain, obtaining the final solution. This procedure is successfully done by Matlab.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the Laplace transform as a tool first and possible applications to linear ODE second.

Comment: I found http://josephcslater.github.io/solve-ode.html using a rather ancient version of sympy. It appears that also the more recent can not do symbolic differentiation on their own, tested with `x = inverse_laplace_transform(X(s),s,t)` to get the two variables connected, and then `laplace_transform(x.diff(t),t,s)` just gives the representation of the construction back.

Comment: Yes, this is also my experience. I want to address this issue to the SymPy team. Du you have any e-mail address to the developer team?